# Placeholder value didn't work in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-8

I have been created webpage using html,css and jqueries.

I fixed maximum issues in IE8. Still i am struggling in placeholder value in form.

For that i tried,

I added below scripts in my head tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-placeholder/2.0.8/jquery.placeholde‌​r.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And i added inputs before closing body tag:

```
<script>$('input, textarea').placeholder();</script>
```

Above those scripts are placed in my index.html.

This is header.html:

```
<form action="#" method="get" id="search-form" role="search" class="large--right">
         <input name="q" type="text" id="search-field" placeholder="Search store..." class="hint">
         <button type="submit" value="" name="submit" id="search-submit" class="icon-fallback-text">
         <span class="icon icon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span>
         <span class="fallback-text">Search</span>
         </button>
      </form>
```

But it didn't work, May i know, these are all is correct.. If not, can you please give me suggestions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the error that you're seeing here? Also, what's your HTML?

Comment: Maybe load `jquery.placeholde‌​r.min.js` after `jquery.min.js`? Check you developer console for errors.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara: i replaced .. but still stays same.

Comment: You should try jquery's older version which supports IE8 (1.10.1). The version you are using(2.1.3) doesn't support IE8.

Comment: may i know.. can you please some of older version @Mr_Green

Comment: @rani use latest file in `1.x.x` of jquery.. like `1.10.1` or `1.11.1`. If you want to support IE8, don't use jquery versions with `2.x.x`.

Comment: and another one important point is, placeholder value displayed in IE8 in another one input type..

Comment: @rani it seems you also need to level down the version of jquery placeholder to `1.8.3`.. just try once.. here is the [link](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder/tree/v1.8.7)

Comment: okay @Mr_Green: is this correct?     <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-placeholder/1.8.3/jquery.placeholder.min.js"></script>

Comment: @rani are you sure the jquery placeholder url is valid? I was redirected here to not found page. **[This is the correct link](https://rawgit.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder/v1.8.7/jquery.placeholder.min.js)**

Comment: @Mr_Green: where i can your link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [THIS](https://github.com/dperini/nwxforms) plugin.

Check demo of placeholder here [**HERE**](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/598365/html5forms/html5forms.html)->

Use this Code

```
<!--[if lte IE 10]>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://linux.aress.net/smudev/js/nwxforms.js"></script>    
      <script type="text/javascript">window.onload = Function('nwxforms(this)');</script>
  <![endif]-->
```

Take JS from my website.

I suggest you to take JS file from here [HERE](http://linux.aress.net/smudev/js/nwxforms.js). And then put in your folder and use relative path like :

`<script type="text/javascript" src="YourjsFolder/nwxforms.js"></script>`

Comment: its working fine ie8.. but i just confused to try in my page.

Comment: can you please help me, how to use.. can i download zip file from your link?

Comment: Really :) I used it in all projects . Check here my IE9 preview ,  http://postimg.org/image/npxd5d36z/  You clear browser cache , you may be missing something !

Comment: i don't have ie9, 10.. for that i am using browser stack.. in browser stack window 7 ->ie9 didn't work..

Comment: @rani , Hi mam , forget that browsrestack ! Our 3 testers in company TESTED this on IE8,IE9,IE10 and above on REAL browsers on Machine ,and there was no placeholder Issue .So always TEST on Real browsers NOT on browserstack getting ? Tell me "`Are your clients going see website on Browserstack or Real web browser IE on their PC ??`"

Comment: now in my system only having ie8 @jQuery.PHP.Magento.com.. so for testing for ie9 ,, i tried to use browser stack.

Comment: Then dont use browserstack. Use some other PC with IE9 installed

Comment: And 1 more it is proved that browserstack is NOT perfect . The placeholder worked on my PC on IE9 and its not working on browserstack. So its working mam.Always use Real browsers on other PC if you dont have

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70447/discussion-between-rani-and-jquery-php-magento-com).

Answer (score 1):

When copying your JS files to my local environment, I got a really odd URL for the placeholder JS code:

```
http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-placeholder/2.0.8/jquery.placeholde%C3%A2%E2%82%AC%C5%92%C3%A2%E2%82%AC%E2%80%B9r.min.js
```

Try copying this URL (it looks the same, but there are some weird characters in yours):

```
//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-placeholder/2.0.8/jquery.placeholder.min.js
```

Comment: Yes, and I still think there's a hidden character in the URL for placeholder.  Update the URL with what I posted, make sure jQuery is loaded before placeholder, and move down to jQuery 1.10.1 (due to IE8 support).  I'm not getting any errors using your code after these fixes.

Comment: The best I can do is IE11 in IE8 mode.  I did see an error with jQuery 2.0.8, but moving down to 1.10.1 (as @Mr_Green suggested) got rid of any errors.

Answer (score 1):

```
Try following plugin
```

https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder

or

http://jamesallardice.github.io/Placeholders.js/

or

```
if($.browser.msie){ 
   $('input[placeholder]').each(function(){  

        var input = $(this);        

        $(input).val(input.attr('placeholder'));

        $(input).focus(function(){
             if (input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
                 input.val('');
             }
        });

        $(input).blur(function(){
            if (input.val() == '' || input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
                input.val(input.attr('placeholder'));
            }
        });
    });
};

Its helpful for you
```

Comment: where i can your script @Deena ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you require any jquery placeholder plugin here.

Chrome, firefox and IE10+ already supports `placeholder` attribute for text field.

So, the only browser which you are trying for placeholder is **IE8 and IE9**.

The most of the part to get a placeholder like design can be done using css. and then just to trigger the keypress event, javascript is required.

Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/wv8qd6af/8/)

**CSS**

```
label {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;
    left: 0px;
    color: #CCC;
    top: 0px;
    padding: 2px;
}
.input-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<form action="#" method="get" id="search-form" role="search" class="large--right">
    <div class="input-wrapper">
        <input name="q" type="text" id="search-field" class="hint"></input>
        <label id="label-search-field" for="search-field">Search store...</label>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" value="" name="submit" id="search-submit" class="icon-fallback-text"> <span class="icon icon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span>
 <span class="fallback-text">Search</span>

    </button>
</form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
// Include this function
function placeholder(e, label) {
    var e = e || window.event;
    var el = e.currentTarget || e.srcElement;
    label.style.color = el.value.length ? "transparent" : "";
}


// call like this in your project
var text = document.getElementById('search-field');
text.onkeyup = function (e) {
    var label = document.getElementById('label-search-field');
    placeholder(e, label);
}
```

Comment: @rani I don't know much about nwxforms but I am thinking that if you were only looking to support placeholder in IE8, then nwxforms.js is not required now.

Comment: [According to caniuse, IE9 does not support the `placeholder` attribute](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-placeholder).